# thymeleaf th:onclick doesn't see javascript function

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

I don't know what to do. I tried everything and nothing works.
I would like to use showBattle function from script in button tag.
But it looks like it doesn't see this function.

```
<button th:onclick="'showBattle(\''+${one}+'\',\''+${two}+'\');'">show battle</button>

<script>
    function showBattle(bbx, batx) {
    document.getElementById(bbx).innerHTML = document.getElementById(batx).innerText;
            }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it worked fine for me. I was able to pass two parameters (one, two) from backend (Spring Boot) and display their value using the JavaScript function.

Have you checked your browser's console for any errors that may have occurred?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue.

I had no idea that an argument for document.getElementById(must be a number or a boolean).

So it's strange because id in HTML should not be a number or start with a number.

I used to write id in HTML as a mix of text and number. But in this case, it caused an issue.

Comment: Maybe something else is behind your problem. #1 You can use getElementById with Strings. That can't be the issue. #2 You cannot use String-parameters within the th:onclick-attribute. That's a security-issue and cannot be used since 2.1 (afaik). There is a workaround with th:data-* and this.getAttribute(...). Comment if you need a snippet.

Comment: Really thx for this answer. Snippet would be nice!  for now I found a way to make it work, but in the future your solution would be extremely helpful. I'm sure I will use it many times.